# visual studio code , autocomplete <div> ... </div> typing for React Coding

Tags: react-native, autocomplete

I am using VS code to do React Js coding, generally very good , but some samll inconvienice, for instance , i have to manually type  `<div> ... </div>` and alike everytime, eventhough code autocomplete works very well.

Please advise how can i improve this ?

Comment: what language extension are you using?

Comment: React Native, i think i have installed many language extensions on visual studio code, how can i check which exactly i am using ?

Comment: it's in the bottom right hand corner. you probably want to be using the Babel ES6/ES7 extension.

Comment: i just checked, I use Babel Javascript, without saying whether its ES6/ES7, or not . But i have installed  Babel ES6/ES7 on VS code as i checked